# Como saber se o teclado(keyboard) está visível?

Tags: java, android

Existe algum método que me diga quando o teclado aparece e some?

Comment: Você quer saber se o teclado está visível ou como mostrar\esconder ele?

Answer (score 2):

Não existe nenhum método direto para conseguir isso.
O que podemos fazer é verificar se a altura do nosso `layout` foi alterado.

Para isso, declaremos um método que será executado quando o nosso `Layout`tiver o seu estado ou visibilidade alterada.

```
final View activityRootView = findViewById(R.id.activityRoot);
activityRootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        int heightDiff = activityRootView.getRootView().getHeight() - activityRootView.getHeight();
        if (heightDiff > 100) { // Se são mais de 100 pixels, provávelmente é o keyboard...
            //... faça aqui o que quer quando o teclado passa a ser visível.
        }
     }
});
```

**Notas**

> 1 - Este código deverá se colocado no método `onCreate` da nossa `Activity`.
>   2 - O `Layout root` da `Activity` deverá ter um `Id` atribuido para que possa ser referenciado no código, neste caso é `activityRoot`.
>   3 - Deverá adicionar este atributo à sua `Activity`: `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"`

Adaptado desta resposta do [SO.com](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4737265/2556111)

Answer (score 1):

Tente isso:

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity()
            .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

    if (imm.isAcceptingText()) {
        writeToLog("Visível");
    } else {
        writeToLog("Não visível");
    }
```

Mais detalhes [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4745988/how-do-i-detect-if-software-keyboard-is-visible-on-android-device).